# Refactoring if statements with radiobuttons.checked

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There are two radio buttons which give different prices.
Example: elektric2 is selected and 3 days rent. Electric bike = 200 euro + 30 euro per day (200 eu + (30*3)).

How can I refactor this because I have 60+ lines of code for all the options.

Here is a bit of the entire code:

```cs
if (radioButtonElectric2.Checked && radioButtonADay.Checked)
{
    electric2 = electric2 + 1 * 30;
    labelSubTotal.Text = "Subtotal:€" + electric2.ToString();
}
else if (radioButtonElectric2.Checked && radioButtonThreeDays.Checked)
{
    electric2 = electric2 + 3 * 30;
    labelSubTotal.Text = "Subtotal:€" + electric2.ToString();
}
else if (radioButtonElectric2.Checked && radioButtonSevenDays.Checked)
{
    electric2 = electric2 + 7 * 30;
    labelSubTotal.Text = "Subtotal:€" + electric2.ToString();
}
else if (radioButtonElectrical2.Checked && radioButtonFourteenDays.Checked)
{
    electric2 = electric2 + 14 * 30;
    labelSubTotal.Text = "Subtotal:€" + electric2.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Isolate what changes.  Consolidate your days check to a function that returns the number of days.  eg.  `thisPrice = basePrice + GetDays() * GetDailyRate();`

Comment: If every of your 60+ items look like radioButtonElectricX + radio button for "a day", "3 days" ... + label + amout you should consider creating a UserControl that contains all radio buttons and you only parameterize the text for the first label and the amount(s) so you only need to implement your if's once in the user control and than add your UserControl for every of your 60+ items.

Comment: I think you would better use a drop-down-list here with value and representation for your 1, 3, 7 and 14 selection. You then can simply take the value from the list and multiply that with what you want your price to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation basically boils down to three amounts.

1. Base Price
2. Renting Days
3. Daily Rate

Splitting these three things into individual functions makes your code much simpler.

```
public decimal GetBasePrice()
{
    return 
        radioButtonElectric1.Checked ? 60 :
        radioButtonElectric2.Checked ? 80 :
        radioButtonGas1.Checked ? 55 :
        0;
}
public int GetRentingDays()
{
    return
        radioButtonADay.Checked ? 1 :
        radioButtonThreeDays.Checked ? 3 :
        radioButtonSevenDays.Checked ? 7 :
        radioButtonFourteenDays.Checked ? 14 :
        0;
}
public decimal GetDailyRate()
{
    return 
        radioButtonElectric1.Checked ? 20 :
        radioButtonElectric2.Checked ? 30 :
        radioButtonGas1.Checked ? 25 :
        0;
}
```

In the end the final code is much simpler:

```
decimal subTotal = GetBasePrice() + GetRentingDays() * GetDailyRate();
```